# Error in running expo react native app keeps saying something went wrong either expo app installed mobile and my laptop are connected in same network

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have used the document of react native to create a expo react native app. my Mobile and laptop are connected in same network. When i run i get error stating Something went wrong"

I have tried connecting to mobile tethering or wireless tethering. All possibles options tried. In error log it says as below,

> uncaught error: java.net.socketException: failed to connect to /1XX.XXX.X.11 (port 8081) from / 1XX.XXX.X.81 (port 58572) after 10000 ms

Need to how to resolve this. I tried solutions from Ai tools and Stack over flow.

I am using java 20 , node => v18.17.1, npm=> 9.6.7

One more is i didn't  get tunneling option too.

Comment: These are some possible solutions:
Make sure you are using a stable internet connection.
Check if you are using a vpn on your phone or computer and disconnect it.
Clear cache of expo go in your phone
Login to your expo account in expo go again.
Try other ways to run the app like scan QR code, enter url manually, login to your expo account and select your project
If you are on android phone you can install sdk on your computer and set environment variables so you can run your app on your phone using cable.
sometimes it doesn't just work delete expo go and install it again from play store

Comment: I have tried all the said options. there is no cache in expo , i have tried by uninstalling and re-installing. I know it works with sdk. But need to know why exactly not in expo.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Go to settings on your phone then apps, find expo go and choose Storage and clear cache. Also make sure you are using correct version of expo go that is compatible with your expo version. Sometimes I change my network connection and it works fine.

Comment: hi @user Thanks for your reply. I have formatted my laptop. Now it's working. Possible problems might be  ` 1.  downgraded node js versions  to 16.  then 2. java version as 11, 3. i ran expo start --port 19000.  ` . this made my application to run on any mobile or emulator in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following :

1. Node js to 16 or 18.
2. Java version as 11.
3. Run expo start --port 19000.

   Try without 1st and 2nd step, directly goto step 3 and check once. if not working try all 3 option or else You will have to end up with formatting your laptop instead of wasting time.